# Laravel Eloquent (PDO): Check that Transaction is Active

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I feel that this should be a simple answer.  However, I haven't been able to find a direct answer in the documents or anywhere else.

In the Laravel PHP framework, I have a situation similar to the following where I open a database-transaction:

*(Of course, my example is grossly simplified from the real-world stuff I'm working with, so please refrain from "why are you doing it this way" type responses).  It's the principle that interests me.*

```
try {

    if ($conditions == $criteria) {
       DB::connection('oracle')->beginTransaction();
    }
    // blah...
```

Later on in the code, I simply want to check whether a transaction is on-going.  The pseudo-code for my condition statement would look something like this:

```
    if ( DB::connection('oracle')->transactionIsOngoing() ) {

        // do some stuff with the on-going transaction
        DB::connection('oracle')->commit();

        // if I were to execute "DB::connection('oracle')->transactionIsOngoing()"
        // again here it would return FALSE, because the commit command has
        // completed the open transaction

    }
```

What is the actual code that I should use to replace `DB::connection('oracle')->transactionIsOngoing()` with?

Comment: `Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface::transaction` has a `transactionLevel` property which returns the number of active transactions, not sure if this is any use to you. https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.html#method_transactionLevel

Comment: @joe You're right.  The answer really is that simples!  Put it as an answer. :-)

Comment: Added as an answer @cartbeforehorse, glad it helped!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Illuminate\Database\ConnectionInterface::transaction` has a `transactionLevel` property which returns the number of active transactions.

Documentation can be found here: https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/ConnectionInterface.html#method_transactionLevel

Comment: Of course this is just an interface. If you want to get the actual transaction level you should use `Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::transactionLevel()`

Answer (score 2):

To get the transaction level you can use

```
Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::transactionLevel();
```

it returns integer